# Combine Makefile and docker-compose on Flask app

Tags: docker

I write my [first Flask app](https://github.com/trouchet/appy) ever. I bring some good practices I learned: unit testing, fixtures, endpoints, Makefile, and docker encapsulation.

The commands on Makefile make my life less naggy. Therefore, it seems good to bring both together. I tried, maybe not my best effort on the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/trouchet/appy/blob/main/Dockerfile). Do you mind helping me with the error log below?

```
appy_app    | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056
appy_app    |   throw err;
appy_app    |   ^
appy_app    | 
appy_app    | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/app/make'
appy_app    |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1053:15)
appy_app    |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:898:27)
appy_app    |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)
appy_app    |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
appy_app    |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
appy_app    |   requireStack: []
appy_app    | }
appy_app    | 
appy_app    | Node.js v19.4.0
```

As @DavidMaze remarks, I changed the first line on Dockerfile to `FROM python:3.6-alpine`, but still receive a node-related error. Weird.

Comment: You seem to have quoted a Node error message, not anything related to Python, and neither of these languages would normally use Make as a build tool.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I will do my best. The reference to node is because of first Dockerfile line "FROM node:19-alpine"